# How to use AWS ACM Private with Docker Node.js + nginx proxy?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, ssl

i'm trying to use the private CA generated on AWS ACM but i dont know what to do with Certificate.pem and CertificateChain.pem that is generated.

edit: See my answer below.

Comment: If you want to use your generated certificate try to import it on ACM where your privatekey.pem will go under private key, certificate.pem under certifcate and certificatechain.pem under certificate chain body fields.

Comment: thanks @kru, can you explain me how i can generate the privatekey.pem? i can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever see this on future:

AWS ACM Private CA doesn't support exporting private key, since it only works inside aws ecosystem.

If you want to use a SSL certificate on another host, you need to use another provider.

Answer (score 0):

For importing the private key, you need to generate one from your end first, create a csr & private key before you ask for ssl certificate to the provider. Once you have the private key, you can import all three (private key, certificate & certificate chain body) to AWS ACM.